# max speed <--> time discretization

Tags: finite-difference, diffusion

I'm working on a heat diffusion problem,
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\kappa T^{5/2}\,\vec{\nabla}T\right)
$$

I know that, after discretization, the time step for the 1D case becomes,
$$
dt= \frac{\rho\,dx^2}{\kappa T_{max}^{5/2}}
$$
Does this imply/mean that the maximum wave speed is
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\kappa T_{max}^{5/2}}{\rho\,dx}
$$
or would I have to analyze this differently to get the wavespeed?

Comment: What is $\rho$ here?

Comment: Density. This is being attached to a hydro code

Comment: What do you mean by 'the time step becomes'? I suspect you interprete the CFL condition in the wrong way...

Comment: @Jan: This time step was computed in [Reale 1995](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6086303688817436807&hl=en&as_sdt=0,41). I admit I removed a factor of order unity, but that's the essence of $dt$ for this problem. All I am asking is if it's valid to use $dx/dt$ to get the wavespeed, or do I have to do something different.

Comment: Since $dt$ and $dx$ is your personal choice, I doubt that you can use them to get a characteristic of the actual continuous equation.

Comment: @Jan: That makes sense. Now the question is how do I calculate the characteristic speed of this PDE?

Comment: What do you want to have? There is no wave speed of a heat diffusion, see @WolfgangBangerth's answer. Or are you simply about stability of your numerical scheme??

Comment: @Jan: I am adding this to a hydro code based on another hydro code. Their version uses explicit method and computes $dt$ based on the $dt$ I gave in the Q. My code computes $dt$ based on hydro wavespeeds, I need to compare the wavespeed of the PDE to the hydro wavespeeds.

Comment: Then you have to define, what is the wavespeed of your PDE.

Comment: @Jan: That's what *I'm* asking

Comment: Then you maybe should rephrase your question and ask 'What is a suitable analogon to wave speed for heat diffusion in comparison with hydro eqns?'

Answer (score 2):

For the heat equation, the wave speed is infinite and this is reflected by the fact that you are solving a globally coupled differential equation if you are using an implicit time stepping scheme.